# How to increase price with percentage?

Tags: sql

For example

```
SELECT product_c, price, price 'New Price'
```

I wanted to increase the price by 20%

Comment: Are you looking to do it in a select, or actually update the table? Also do you care about possible rounding issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT product_c, price, (price* 1.20) as new_price FROM Table;
```